# What does MALC mean in a user agent string?

Tags: internet-explorer, user-agent

I'm working on troubleshooting a feature that works for most users, but does not work for some. The users that have reported the issue seem to all have the following user agent string:

User agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; MALC)

So looking at the string it's an IE9, on Windows 7, 32-bit version of Internet Explorer is running on a 64-bit processor, running as IE9 (Trident/5.0 and MSIE 9.0 match).

However, I have no idea what MALC means. Googling it didn't get me any leads. Please help.

Comment: It seems that my accepted answer is incorrect. See the other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21553498/830125. If you un-accept mine I will delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The informations above are wrong.
MALC doesn´t Mean Multiple Access Line Concentrator. MALC is a OEM identificator for Lenovo Thinkpads or Laptops.

See:

http://www.whatismybrowser.com/developers/unknown-user-agent-fragments

http://user-agents.me/browser/mozilla50-windows-nt-61-wow64-trident70-malc-rv110-like-gecko